# Syncing SQL table structures

Tags: mysql

I have many users on my server, each user has their own database, with a set of tables. I also have a template database with a set of tables that I duplicate when someone signs up.

What I need to do is, if I make a change to the template database like; add a table, add a column, delete a column... I need to sync this database structure to the other databases.

Is there any way of doing this without writing a special script to check formats and make the appropriate changes?

Comment: No, there's no way to do it automatically AFAIK.

Comment: I don't mean fully automatic. I mean something that can be done in one or two SQL queries.

Comment: Even a way to copy a table structure to another table would be effective.

Comment: There's `CREATE TABLE table1 LIKE table2`, but that can't be used to modify an existing table. I don't think there's anything equivalent for `ALTER TABLE`.